# Typewriter Effect on Internet Explorer: Does not delete Strings?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

JS Typewriter Code Below.

What is my issue?  My strings do not delete on Internet Explorer:  [image: screenshot example attached of run-on strings]

My question:  How can I fix this?

Is my typewriter effect working perfectly on Chrome & Edge Browsers?  YES!  Deletes the strings and proceeds to the next string as coded.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Mike

```js
var app = document.getElementById('typewriter');
 
 var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
     loop: true,
     delay: 40,
 });
   typewriter.typeString('travel & leisure')
    .pauseFor(550)
      .deleteAll(1)
    .pauseFor(900)
 typewriter.typeString('coffee shops')
    .pauseFor(550)
      .deleteAll(1)
    .pauseFor(900)
     .typeString('auto dealers')
     .pauseFor(550)
      .deleteAll(1)
    .pauseFor(900)
     .typeString('realtors')
     .pauseFor(550)
     .deleteAll(1)
      .pauseFor(900)
   .typeString('lawyers')
     .pauseFor(550)
     .deleteAll(1)
      .pauseFor(900)
   .typeString('dentists')
     .pauseFor(550)
     .deleteAll(1)
      .pauseFor(900)
      .start()
```

```css
#typewriter {
     font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
     font-size: 39.8px;
    font-weight: lighter;
   color: #898989
 }
 .Typewriter__cursor {
font-size: 45px; 
  color: #919191;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
</style>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect/dist/core.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Parallax -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.6.2/rellax.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var targets = '.banner-thumbnail-wrapper #thumbnail img, .index-section #thumbnail img, .index-section:first-child .slide .thumb-image';
    if (document.querySelector(targets)) {
      var rellax = new Rellax(targets, {
        speed: -4,
        center: true
      });
    }
  });
</script>
<!-- end Parallax -->

<div id="typewriter"></div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` And what is `Typewriter`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Not sure if you -1 my question; however, this JS works perfect on Chrome & Edge... can you elaborate on your comment above?  I am just trying to find a solution "aka" what needs to be added or changed in the JS to make it work properly on all browsers?  I am new, so please, please, dumb it down to me.  I've looked on Google and am stuck.  Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough code in the question to see what might be going on. Please edit the snippet until it runs (in Chrome) so we have a [mcve] to debug. (It currently does not work perfectly in Chrome - it throws a syntax error.)

Comment: This was my first time entering my code in this site.  I added the JS, HTML, and CSS.  I have this in the Code Block before the JS:  <p style="text-align:left;"><span <div id="typewriter"></div>   (I wasn't sure where to place this in the example code here??)  In my browsers; Chrome & Edge, shows that it types/deletes perfect.  Thoughts on this?  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Looks like you put HTML code in the JS section, which was causing a syntax error.

Comment: I fixed the code here.  Check it out now if you have time.

Comment: <script> wraps the JS but for some reason it does not here.. when I wrap it here it throws the run code snippet off... in my code block I wrap the JS in <script>

Comment: The error is: `Unable to get property 'removeChild' of undefined or null reference`. So somewhere in https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@2.5.2/dist/core.js , the outer object is undefined, but minified code is unreadable...

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time. - Mike